# `json_encode` not working with explode

Tags: php

I have a string containing numbers separated by comma. ie, `1,2,3,6...`. I have removed the comma using explode. Now i want to match the corresponding values in database.

My Code is,

```
$color = "1,2,3,9,5";
$color_split = explode(",", $color);

foreach($color_split as $item)
{
    $select_color = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product_color WHERE color_id = '$item'";
    $select_color_q = mysqli_query($c, $select_color) or die(mysqli_error($c));
    $length =   mysqli_num_rows($select_color_q);

    if($length > 0)
    {
        while($select_color_r = mysqli_fetch_object($select_color_q))
        {
            $var[] = $select_color_r;
        }
        $var = json_encode($var);
        echo '{"color_list":'.$var.'}';
    }
    else
    {
        $arr    =   array('status'=>"notfound");
        echo '{"color_list":['.json_encode($arr).']}';
    }
}
```

Now the output is,

```
{"color_list":[{"color_id":"1","color_name":"White","color_code":"#f2f2f2"}]}

and one error,

Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in C:\wamp\www\jithin\get_color.php on line 18
```

line 18 contains `$var[] = $select_color_r;`

My required output is,

```
{"color_list":[{"color_id":"1","color_name":"White","color_code":"#f2f2f2"},{"color_id":"2","color_name":"Black","color_code":"#000000"},{"color_id":"3","color_name":"Red","color_code":"#F000000"},...]}
```

Comment: You didn't define `$var` as array.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois : after define `$var` the result is `{"color_list":[{"color_id":"1","color_name":"White","color_code":"#f2f2f2"}]}{"color_list":[{"color_id":"2","color_name":"Black","color_code":"#000000"}]}...`. I want result as `{"color_list":[{"color_id":"1","color_name":"White","color_code":"#f2f2f2"},{"color_id":"2","color_name":"Black","color_code":"#000000"},{"color_id":"3","color_name":"Red","color_code":"#F000000"},...]}`

Comment: Then you need to check the array structure if it is as you want it. If not you need to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `foreach` and `explode` over here you can simply update your `MySql` query and `code` like as

```
$color = "1,2,3,9,5";
$select_color = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product_color WHERE color_id IN ($color)";
$select_color_q = mysqli_query($c, $select_color) or die(mysqli_error($c));
$arr['color_list'] = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($select_color_q) > 0)
    {
        while($select_color_r = mysqli_fetch_object($select_color_q))
        {
            $var[] = $select_color_r;
        }

    }else{
        $var = array('status'=>"notfound");
    }

$arr['color_list'] = $var;
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

you set `$var` as string in here :

```
 $var = json_encode($var);
```

but in the next step of foreach you want to use `$va`r as array.

```
 $var[] = $select_color_r;
```

just remove the following line :

```
    $var = json_encode($var);
```

and change this line :

```
echo '{"color_list":'.$var.'}';
```

to

```
echo '{"color_list":'.json_encode($var);.'}';
```

Comment: now the result is `{"color_list":[{"color_id":"1","color_name":"White","color_code":"#f2f2f2"}]}{"color_list":[{"color_id":"1","color_name":"White","color_code":"#f2f2f2"},{"color_id":"2","color_name":"Black","color_code":"#000000"},...]}`

Comment: i dont want first `{"color_list":[{"color_id":"1","color_name":"White","color_code":"#f2f2f2"}]}`